# Logback - possible to get AsyncAppender's current queue's size?

Tags: logback

Is it possible to get Logback's AsyncAppender's current queue size?

Here's the relevant section of our config:

```
<appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
  <queueSize>1000</queueSize>
  <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>
  <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</appender>
```

Comment: were you able to capture this information?

Comment: no, I never did find a way to do it.